# Why linux can read windows 10 files from ntfs mounpoint

Tags: command-line, ntfs, editor

I test to read some read only files (*. dll) . Why this is resricted to do, its not normal behaviour. Linux user can normaly read and modify all kind files. This must be codet inside software (ubuntu, lubuntu)

Some text editors (featherpad) also see different files list (show hide is on) what I see in the shell, and some files on the ntfs mount point not look a like normal ntfs files - maybe microsoft change ntfs format, thats really bad

Comment: Linux can read ntfs file systems because someone wrote the code to do so: https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/libfsntfs1 -- show the mount command you use.

Comment: Yes I know how to mount filesystem to read/write. The problem is that some editor program not see same list of files what I see on the shell. There is windows desktop.ini, inside that is a link to dll what windows use to show directory - can hide some files and directors and also show dummy file names. I quest that inside ubundu there is a part what can use that dll same way in linux!

Answer (score 0):

> Why linux can read windows 10 files from ntfs mounpoint

Because we have a driver that can transform with Windows want to show in a Linux format.

> Linux user can normaly read and modify all kind files

No. We can not read Windows DLL's that are encrypted or that are compressed.

> maybe microsoft change ntfs format, thats really bad

Not really. As soon as the driver spots a problem it will fall back to read only. Best example: the driver refuses to mount as writable if you use hibernation to turn windows off. Microsoft can not change ntfs significantly without creating a new windows version and without informing 3rd party software vendors.

Comment: Thanks for answers.If user use unix/linux then its normaly read any files, only output is problem. So someone write part in linux to stop even open it.